# How to detect if I app open via URL(Deeplinking) or normally launch in ionic 2?

Tags: ionic2, deep-linking

I have  implemeted the deeplinking in our application in our application it is working properly but i have the function that is created in our app.component.ts file and i will check the user is app open via deeplinking or not tell me anyone it is possible to detect app open via URL or not?